# How to setup icons for content elements or plugins in a TYPO3 extension

Tags: typo3

How are icons configured for content elements and plugins? Is there a shortcut to make it possible to configure it only once and not in 3 places?

AFAIK, there are 3 places to configure **icons** when creating new custom content elements & plugins in the **TYPO3 backend**:

1. New Content Element wizard
2. What is visible in the CType / list_type select list when you edit the content element (CE)

[image]

3. What is visible in the Page Layout view

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware of any shortcuts, this is the way I do it.

First, register an icon identifier to reference your icon, see official TYPO3 documentation: [Icon API > Registration](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Icon/Index.html#registration).

You can register for example SVG icons or Font Awesome icons.

---

Next, make sure the icon is configured correctly in these 3 places:

**1. New Content Element (CE) wizard**

Is configured in Page TSconfig

e.g. (use the previously registered icon identifier)

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.show:=addToList(extkey_plugin)
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.elements.extkey_plugin {
  iconIdentifier = my-icon
  # ...
}
```

TYPO3 documentation: [Add content elements to the Content Element Wizard](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/ContentElementsWizard.html)

---

**2. CType / list_type select list:**

For Extbase plugins this is configured via registerPlugin (parameter 4)

`Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'ExtkeyInCamelCase', 
    'PluginIdentifier', 
    'plugin title', 
    // icon 
    'my-icon');
```

TYPO3 documentation: [Extbase Plugin registration](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/main/en-us/4-FirstExtension/7-configuring-the-plugin.html#plugin-registration-extensionutility-registerplugin)

For non-Extbase plugins, the icon can be passed via [addPlugin](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/HowTo/FrontendPlugin/AbstractPlugin.html#tca-configuration).

For content elements, this can be configured via TCA:

`Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(
'tt_content',
'CType',
[
    'Title',
    // plugin signature: extkey_identifier
    'myext_plugin',
    // icon identifier
    'my-icon',
```

TYPO3 documentation: [Register the content element](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html#register-the-content-element)

---

**3. In the Page Layout view:**

For content elements, you can set it in TCA:

`Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['ctrl']['typeicon_classes'][$pluginname] = 'my-icon';
```

TYPO3 documentation: [typeicon_classes](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/TypeiconClasses.html)

For plugins, the icon in the page layout view is already automatically registed via registerPlugins (since TYPO3 v11.5.12).

Comment: Since at least v11.5.12, `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin()` changes the icon in "Page Layout" view, too.