# How can I set the icon for a content element in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

In `tt_content` I have added something like this, and set the core icon 'content-image':

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(
        'tt_content',
        'CType',
        [
                'My Element',
                'myelement',
                'content-image'
        ],
        'textmedia',
        'after'
);
```

And this works in the 'Type' dropdown menu. However, when in Page or List view it always shows the default text icon. How do I change this to match the type menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just found another question with a real good answer - mainly the same
> as mine, but better structured - have a look:
> [How to setup icons for content elements or plugins in a TYPO3 extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70905320/how-to-setup-icons-for-content-elements-or-plugins-in-a-typo3-extension)

You may revisit https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html with a full overview.

The `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem()` registers the icon only for the select field.

For the "new content element" wizard you have to provide a proper TSconfig part https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html#add-it-to-the-new-content-element-wizard

```
// example - you must adopt for your element
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems {
   // add the content element to the tab "common"
   common {
      elements {
         examples_newcontentelement {
            iconIdentifier = content-text
            title = LLL:EXT:examples/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:examples_newcontentelement_title
            description = LLL:EXT:examples/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:examples_newcontentelement_description
            tt_content_defValues {
               CType = examples_newcontentelement
            }
         }
      }
      show := addToList(examples_newcontentelement)
   }
}
```

If you want to use a custom image, you have to register it. Either in ext_localconf.php with proper icon calls or depending on the core version with the simple `Configuration/Icons.php` file.

See for 11.5+ https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Icon/Index.html or before see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Icon/Index.html

The next part is then TCA configuration for the specific table. Generic table icon file is configured with:

```
// or $GLOBALS if done as TCA Override for a existing table
return [
  // ...
  'ctrl' => [
    'iconFile' => '',
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
```

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/Iconfile.html

Table with types can have different icons per types, which can be set with `typeicon_classes`
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/TypeiconClasses.html#ctrl-reference-typeicon-classes - however, this depends on the type field. For tt_content this is "CType". So this helps only for real content elements which registeres as own `CType` - and not as `list CType` with a subtype `list_type`. For extbase plugin this is done with the proper plugin registration in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'ExtkeyInCamelCase', 
    'PluginIdentifier', 
    'plugin title', 
    // icon 
    'my-icon');
```

Comment: I have the tsconfig `iconIdentifier` set already for the wizard. But neither setting changes what icon is in Page/List modes?

Comment: Added more infos - and added a link to another question with a good answer (better than mine here).